# Flash Drive Boot Issue

Tags: boot, 13.04, usb-drive, bootloader

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 onto a flash drive and everything seemed to go smoothly, but after it told me to restart (and I did), it said t insert a boot device (which should be the flash drive, as I have my other drives removed).  What should I do to get it to boot?  Do I need a bootloader or something of the type?

Comment: Is GRUB pre-installed? Or do I need to add it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the CMOS options so that the Flash drive is available for booting before everything but the CD drive. You can do this by clicking F2 (on my laptop! Sometimes the Delete or F12 button) as you boot up.
Next, using your keyboard left and right arrows, navigate to Boot and follow the onscreen instructions

Comment: I have an Asus Rampage IV Extreme.  So the BIOS is a little complex. I am able to use the demo from a separate flash drive (actually the one I used to install Ubuntu on this current flash drive), so it is able to boot from USB.

Comment: You really need to change the boot order else Grub will try the first entry and continue until it reaches the end of the list. I expect that the flash drive has not been selected as a bootable option.

Comment: As soon as you turn your computer on, start tapping the "Del" key steadily till you get in to the bios then go to the Boot option, you should be able to sort it out there.

Comment: I am aware of where to sort it out, but if the flash drive is the only storage device connected, why would I need to change the order?

Answer (score 0):

On my asrock z68 board theres a little trick, maybe its similar:
ON boot selection there are 2 options for USB boot:

1. USB: **__**
2. UEFI: USB Hard Drive

Option 2. is correct, option 1. gives "Insert boot device"